# Java double calculation problems

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a Trafficsimulation which is based on a grid system. For some reason the line of code, which calculates how many tiles i have to add always returns 0. I have tried it without the variables but it still doesn't work.

```
double blocksToAdd = o.getVelocity()*((1000/Main.FPS)/1000);
```

Currently the velocity is equal to 1.0f and the Simulation runs at 10 FPS, so `blocksToAdd` should be `0.1`, but it always returns `0`.

Comment: Can you post `Main.FPS` declaration?

Comment: I think your Main.FPS is integer variable. Make it double

Comment: Integer arithmetic may be causing that. Change your `1000` for `1000.0` to force floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Main.FPS` is an `int`, `1000/Main.FPS` is also an `int`, equal to `100`. You then proceed to calculate `100/1000`. Since this is an [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), only the "whole" part is taken, giving `0`.

Using floating point literals will cause Java to use floating point division, which should produce the correct result:

```
double blocksToAdd = o.getVelocity() * ((1000.0 /Main.FPS ) / 1000.0);
// Here --------------------------------------^--------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely due to integer division tuncating the fraction.

Replace the first 1000 with 1000.0 and all will be well. (The latter is a floating point double literal which causes the division to be computed in floating point.) There are other remedies but I find this one to be the clearest.